# highlight more than one cell for excel conditional formatting

Tags: excel

I am using excel and conditional formatting on column D

It just says if value = 'this' change background colour etc. it works fine, but how can i make the background colour of columns D,E,F change the same of column D = 'this.value' ?

Comment: JMP allows formulas to access color.  I bet VBA does too.  You might have to go that direction, where a VBA macro sets a constant background color.

Comment: i just want to keep it simple within excel

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using a formula with the "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" option

Select columns D, E and F and set formula to

`=$D1="this"`

and format as required

Note the $ - that's essential